# Joi validations when there is an array elements

Tags: typescript, joi

I want to implement the following validations using Joi.

My schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
   createdDate: Joi.string().required(),
   futureDate: Joi.string().allow("").optional(),
   Events: Joi.array().items({
      status: Joi.string().required(),
      type: Joi.string().required()       
   })
});
```

My input request will be like this. I am validating the following request with the above schema and validation. If `Events.type == "XYZ"` then `futureDate` is required else it's optional.

```
   {
            "createdDate": "2021-02-02T00:00:00",           
            "futureDate": "2021-02-02T00:00:00",
            "Events": [
                {
                    "status": "P",
                    "type": "ABC"
                },
                {
                    "status": "S",
                    "type": "XYZ"
                }            
                
            ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to combine [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) with [.has](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayhasschema):

```
Joi.object({
   createdDate: Joi.string().required(),
   futureDate: Joi.string().allow("").optional(),
   Events: Joi.array().items({
      status: Joi.string().required(),
      type: Joi.string().required()       
   })
}).when(Joi.object({ Events: Joi.array().items({
    status: Joi.string().required(),
    type: Joi.string().required()       
  })
  .required()
  .has(Joi.object({ status: Joi.string(), type: 'XYZ' })) }).unknown(), {
       then: Joi.object({ futureDate: Joi.required() })
})
```

What we are "saying" here is, when the `Events` array exists and contains at least one element with `type: 'XYZ'`, then `futureDate` is required.

Comment: This will show always createdDate required even though type is not 'XYZ'. But I need if type != 'XYZ' then createdDate  should be optional.

Comment: Do you mean the `futureDate`? I just updated the post. Could you please try again?

Comment: Now also same its not saying futureDate is mandatory when type : 'XYZ'

Comment: I've tested with this data `{ createdDate: '123', Events: [{ status: '123', type: 'XYZ' }] }` and it says `Validation Error: "futureDate" is required`. Could you please provide an example that it's not working?

Comment: const validation = schema.validate(data);
// data is input data

Comment: Your schema is not right, you are not following my example. You wrote `Events` instead of `shipmentEvents` in your `.when`, and your `.has` should look like this: `.has(Joi.object({ status: Joi.string(), type: 'pickup date changed' })) }).unknown()`.

Comment: Here's the schema: `Joi.object({ 
  createdDate: Joi.string().required(), 
  currentEstimatedDeliveryDate: Joi.string().allow("").optional(), 
  shipmentEvents: Joi.array().items({ 
    status: Joi.string().required(),
    type: Joi.string().required() }) 
  }).when(Joi.object({ shipmentEvents: Joi.array().items({ status: Joi.string().required(), type: Joi.string().required() }) .required().has(Joi.object({ status: Joi.string(), type: 'pickup date changed' })) }).unknown(), { then: Joi.object({ currentEstimatedDeliveryDate: Joi.required() }) }) `

Comment: No No instead of exposing my actual work I shared sample request and schema. I followed the example exactly but still its not working.

Comment: I understand, but if you change the schema, you need to change it properly, and you didn't, you have mixed `shipmentEvents` with `Events`.

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. It works. What if I want to add one more condition lets say first condtion type == 'pickup date changed' then currentEstimatedDeliveryDate is required, second condition if type === 'test data' then shipmentEvents.status is required and currentEstimatedDeliveryDate is required else optional.

Comment: If you think my answer was helpful, please upvote. And if you have more questions, I suggest you create a new post.